# "extends Array<Object>" not working as expected in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic type for normalizing classes, but my use of Array is not working as I would expect.

```
 interface IBuilding {
  buildingID: number,
  name: string,
  construction: ("wood" | "concrete" | ""),
  website: string,
  address?: IAddress,
  apartments?: IApartment[]
}

type Normalized<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends number ? number :
  T[K] extends string ? string :
  T[K] extends number[] ? number[] :
  T[K] extends string[] ? string[] :
  T[K] extends Function ? never :
  T[K] extends Array<Object> ? number[] :
  T[K] extends Object ? number :
  T[K]
};

let building: Normalized<IBuilding>;
```

I would expect the building.apartments type to be number[], but instead it is number.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: do you mean at runtime? can you give an example of how the building object is being made?

Comment: The object was created pretty straightforward. Just created a new const with the Normalized<IBuilding> type, and hardcoded each of the properties. Matt seems to be right about this being an issue with the fact that its an optional property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `strictNullChecks` because that's the only way I can reproduce the behavior described.  Since the `apartments` field of `IBuilding` is optional, its effective type is `undefined | IApartment[]`, which does not extend `Array<Object>` because of the `undefined`.  However, even before `Normalized` is called, the conditional type `T[K] extends Object ? number : T[K]` is simplified to `number`, because the compiler assumes that anything that is internally considered a "type variable" (including unsimplified lookup types) is constrained by the empty object type `{}`, which is assignable to `Object`.  Clearly this assumption is incorrect if `T[K]` ends up including `null` or `undefined`.  I filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26796).

To get the behavior that I assume you want, you can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which will break up any and all unions in the input, including unions involving `null` and `undefined`.  I think this should be acceptable for your use case.

```
type NormalizeOne<T> =
  T extends number ? number :
  T extends string ? string :
  T extends number[] ? number[] :
  T extends string[] ? string[] :
  T extends Function ? never :
  T extends Array<Object> ? number[] :
  T extends Object ? number :
  T;  // not reached due to compiler issue

type Normalized<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: NormalizeOne<T[K]>;
};
```

If you don't want to break up all unions, you could use a non-distributive conditional type and instead just add specific cases for unions with `undefined`:

```
type NormalizeOne<T> =
  [T] extends [number] ? number :
  [T] extends [number | undefined] ? number | undefined :
  [T] extends [string] ? string :
  [T] extends [string | undefined] ? string | undefined :
  [T] extends [number[]] ? number[] :
  [T] extends [number[] | undefined] ? number[] | undefined :
  [T] extends [string[]] ? string[] :
  [T] extends [string[] | undefined] ? string[] | undefined :
  [T] extends [Function] ? never :
  [T] extends [Array<Object>] ? number[] :
  [T] extends [Array<Object> | undefined] ? number[] | undefined :
  [T] extends [Object] ? number :
  T;  // not reached due to compiler issue
```

(It's probably possible to remove some of the duplication there by defining an auxiliary type alias.)

Comment: It seems you were right that the issue was with the fact that it was an optional property. But your solution worked great. I don't know enough typescript to have come up with a solution like yours, so thanks!